# Erro B2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1667, SQLSTATE=42858 ao salvar objeto no banco db2

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, db2

Tenho uma simples aplicação que pega uma mensagem do kafka e salva no db2 , por algum motivo estou obtendo o seguinte erro ao salvar:

> Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1667, SQLSTATE=42858, SQLERRMC=D_ODS_STREAM_PORTALONE.TR_RECEP;ORGANIZE BY COLUMN;FINAL|NEW|OLD TABLE, DRIVER=4.31.10

Segue minha classe de consumer:

```
/**
 * Recebe a mensagem do EventHub da Azure utilizando Kafka
 */
@Component
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConsumer {


    private final PortalONERepository portalONERepository;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    public KafkaConsumer(PortalONERepository portalONERepository, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.portalONERepository = portalONERepository;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "divout")
    @Transactional("transactionManager")
    public void consumeEventHubMessage(String consumerMessage) {
        log.info("Received message from kafka queue: {}", consumerMessage);

        //Convert string message to java object
        try {
            DocumentONE[] documentOne = objectMapper.readValue(consumerMessage, DocumentONE[].class);
            //Salvar cada mensagem no db2
            portalONERepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(documentOne));

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Error receiving message: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

O que poderia estar causando este erro?

Comment: a mensagem de erro não é clara o suficiente para determinar o problema, sugiro olhar cada valor de cada propriedade e ver se foram bem convertidos no mapping, a princípio parece que algum parâmetro não foi corretamente convertido no comando de `insert`

Comment: ja fiz esse teste, acabei de fazer na verdade, removi todos deixei só o id, mesmo assim deu esse erro.

Comment: seu id não é `IDENTITY` na anotation da propriedade? não pode passar valor para uma coluna que é `IDENTITY`

Comment: mas o hibernate passa o valor default, eu peguei o que sai no console e joguei no banco e funciona: insert into d_ods_stream_portalone.tr_recepcao_portal_one (id_recepcao_portal_one) values (default)

Comment: Ou seja se eu pego o comando e jogo manualmente funciona mas pela aplicação não

Comment: Não estou passando, o próprio banco gera o valor

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Resolvemos o problema trocando a tabela de colunar para linear, para situações de aplicações transacionais em tempo real como esta em que se insere linha por linha não seria possível o uso da tabela colunar que e usado para situações de big data em analise de dados e tem funcionamento diferente.
Segue o link da resposta que foi dado no stack overflow em ingles:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74683580/db2-sql-error-sqlcode-1667-sqlstate-42858-while-save-in-db2-database/74684247#74684247

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).